# Memory usage of React Native initial project is very high

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, memory

I use react-native init ProjectName and I track memory use via Xcode. Why the memory use is not very stable and also why the memory usage is so high?

RN version:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.4.1",
  "react-native": "0.56.0"
},
```

[image]

I didn't change any codes of initial RN project yet!

Comment: did you solved it?

Comment: What's other processes? Is it some kind of React Native linked process?